# Pandas; Select rows in one data frame based on this data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas data frames. I want to select a subset of records in one data frame based on whether a field in each record is above a value in this data frame and the same field is below a value in another set.

The following gives me all the records in the first data frame whose value exceeds my cutoff:

```
 roi_upregulated_genes = roi[roi['zscore']>CUTOFF]
```

How do I find out the corresponding zscore in `df_two`. Both data frames have the same column names.

The logic is something like

```
roi_selectively_upregulated_genes = [gene for gene in roi_upregulated_genes if control[gene][zscore] < CUTOFF]
```

How could one do this in Pandas? I can't use the index, I have to cross-reference between tables by the field `gene`.

Comment: Post raw data and current code, it sounds like you want to filter the 2 dfs separately and merge them on gene only if the condition is satisfied in both dfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've not posted any raw data and code this is what I think should work

```
lhs = roi[roi['zscore']>CUTOFF]
rhs = control[control['zscore']<CUTOFF]

combined = lhs.merge(rhs, on='gene', how='inner')
```

This will give you only the genes that are present in both subsets

Comment: Sorry, the data file is quite large, and all the code except for the line I posted was boilerplate. Your solution works though, thanks.